# django display five objects from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

So I just try to build an app in Python Django and I try to display a certain quantity of objects, for example I want to take from the database just first five objects and display it. Another next five objects display on another site and another five objects display on the next site and so on... .How can I do that? I now that I can do for example: mountains = peaks.objects.all() and then with for loop in template display all of objects. But I want just five per site.

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/

Comment: As Willem suggested take a look at the pagination docu (which seems to be exactly what you need) or try to solve your problem with slicing: ```all = YourAwsomeModel.objects.all()``` and then ```first_five = all[:5]... six_to_ten = all[5:10]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generic views for these. Like these

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Peak

class MountainList(ListView):
    model = Peak
    paginate_by = 5
```

In your `urls.py` you should have a pattern like these

```
from .models import MountainList

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('mountains/',MountainList.as_view(),name='mountain_list'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you for advice it helps a lot.